# Sort by associate model with HasMany Relationship CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

- Post hasMany Comment

Comment(id,title,content,is_main). Each Post has at least one comment and must have one comment as main(only 1 comment is main)

I need to sort Post by title of comment which is main, but sorting by virtual fields appears to have been removed in Cake 3.x

Controller:

> $query = $this->Post->find()->contain(["Comment"]);

Template:

> Paginator->sort('comment', "Comment(s)")
>   ?>

Comment: so is it a virtual field? since indeed sorting by virtual fields is not possible in cake 3 by my knowledge

Comment: where is your virtual field ? Looks like you need to sort from associated model's field .. isn't it ?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka: Yep I need to sort table Post by name of main comment :(

Comment: well that is possible as long its not a virtual field

Comment: Why are you writing query in Track controller instead of Post controller ?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka: typos bro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old virtual fields concept has been removed, yes, but defining computed columns / selecting custom columns is very well possible, even though not neccesarily required for what you are trying to do.

Given that there can be only one main comment, you could simply left join your `Comment` (btw. it should be `Comments` and `Posts` if you'd follow the [**CakePHP naming conventions**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)) association on that condition.

```
$this->paginate = [
    // ...
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        // associations and computed columns must be whitelisted, and if
        // you do that, the valid main model columns must be specified too
        'id',
        // ...
        'Comments.title'
    ]
];

$query = $this->Posts
    ->find()
    ->leftJoinWith('Comments', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return $query
            ->where(['Comments.is_main' => true]);
    });

$posts = $this->paginate($query);
```

```
// in your view template

$this->Paginator->sort('Comments.title', 'Main Comment Title');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Pagination > Control which Fields Used for Ordering](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using leftJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-leftjoinwith)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Paginator > Creating Sort Links](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#creating-sort-links)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Paginator > Example Usage](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#example-usage)**

Comment: Thank you so much! It is too clear when you explain it. Thank you! It saves my day!

Comment: Yes, this is perfect solution and better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

At controller:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain'=>['Comments'],
    'sortWhitelist'=>['Comments.comment']
    ];

$posts = $this->paginate($this->Posts);
```

At template:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('Comments.comment') ?>
```

See Here [Sorting Contained Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#sorting-contained-associations) CakePHP3.

This answer works for only hasOne relation.

Comment: Already try your solution but still not work :(. I wonder how we can know what are sorted are title of main comment, because they are many comment per post

Comment: Oh I see.. Do you mean you have one main comment for each post and you need to sort from that main comment ?? If so how would cake know that. May be you need to try other solutions then.

Comment: Yep bro, problem is we have many comment per post, and sort post by main comment. I guess must use left join but I'm new to CakePHP then don't know how to

Comment: ndm has give a quite awesome answer, you can refer it if want to know how to